# Zend_Pdf adding Calibre (ttf) font to PDF

Tags: php, zend-pdf

I am using a gift card generating wordpress plugin. It is using the Zend framework. After looking at other threads on stackoverflow this is how far I have got so far;

```
//load font from file system - last one calibre is the one I added

$pdf = new Zend_Pdf ();
$bold_font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName ( Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD );
$font_regular = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName ( Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA );
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName ( Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD );
$calibre = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath ("/lib/customfonts/CalibreMedium.ttf");

//selecting the font to be used
$page->setFont ( $calibre, 14 );
```

This currently doesn't work. It does not break the website but when attempting to complete checkout it throws a WooCommerce "Internal Server Error" which has been happening every-time I get the Zend php incorrect.

Comment: Not sure how to check them, will google it now. Thanks

Comment: `"/lib/customfonts/CalibreMedium.ttf"` is an absolute path ... chances are if you change it to `"./lib/customfonts/CalibreMedium.ttf"` it will work.

Comment: Just tried, no luck. Also tried to change the path to '.\lib\Zend\Pdf\Resource\Font\customfonts\CalibreMedium.ttf' to make sure it is within the Zend folder, but still the same.